# Ruby on rails ler ficheiro csv e preencher tabela

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tabela-html, csv

Tenho seguinte tabela noticias :

```
create_table "noticia", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "conteudo_id"
    t.integer  "entidade_id"
    t.integer  "imagem_id"
    t.string   "texto"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

e tenho o seguinte um ficheiro .csv onde contem estes campos com o seguinte formato:

Texto_Post, url imagem

Agradecia uma ajuda de como ler o ficheiro e também se necessário é possível alterar a disposição do conteúdo do ficheiro.

Comment: nome de tabela no rails é no plural, "noticias"

Comment: Nesse caso o .csv não tem todos os dados para criar o objeto, certo? como você vai fazer com os relacionamentos?

Comment: `Conteudo.create(titulo: data[0])
 conteudo_id = Conteudo.order("created_at").last.id
 Imagem.create(imagem_url: data[2])
 imagem_id = Imagem.order("created_at").last.id
 Noticium.create(conteudo_id: conteudo_id,entidade_id:  data[1], imagem_id: imagem_id, texto: data[3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para formatar o csv para o formato do AR, use esta gem:

https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Comment: Onde é que coloco esse código ? É o meu primeiro projecto com ruby on rails e não estou muito a vontade..

Comment: você pode colocar no arquivo db/seed.rb, para rodar o seed basta digitar rake db:seed.

Comment: Depende de como vc vai usar @CarlosMachado. Como o seu app vai receber esse .csv? É via upload? Ou o arquivo está em disco e só vai ser carregado 1x?

Comment: @AlexTakitani o arquivo encontra-se sempre em disco

Comment: @CarlosMachado crie uma rake task: http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks